# Writing on text file, accents and special characters not displaying correctly

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, web-crawler, utf

Here's what I'm doing, I'm web crawling for my personal use on a website to copy the text and put the chapters of a book on text format and then transform it with another program to pdf automatically to put it in my cloud. Everything is fine until this happens: special characters are not copying correctly, for example the accent is showed as: \xe2\x80\x99 on the text file and the - is showed as \xe2\x80\x93. I used this (Python 3):

```
    for text in soup.find_all('p'):
        texta = text.text
        f.write(str(str(texta).encode("utf-8")))
        f.write('\n')
```

Because since I had a bug when reading those characters and it just stopped my program, I encoded everything to utf-8 and retransform everything to string with python's method str()

I will post the whole code if anyone has a better solution to my problem, here's the part that crawl the website from page 1 to max_pages, you can modify it on line 21 to get more or less chapters of the book:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def crawl_ATG(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        x= page
        url = 'http://www.wuxiaworld.com/atg-index/atg-chapter-' + str(x) + "/"
        source = requests.get(url)
        chapter = source.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(chapter.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'), 'html.parser')
        f = open('atg_chapter' + str(x) + '.txt', 'w+')
        for text in soup.find_all('p'):
        texta = text.text
            f.write(str(str(texta).encode("utf-8")))
            f.write('\n')
        f.close
        page +=1
    
crawl_ATG(10)
```

I will do the clean up of the first useless lines that are copied later when I get a solution to this problem. Thank you

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? It matters. Read [the Python Unicode howto.](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: I'm using Python 3, thank you for the link I will dig into it carrefully. @BobDylan

Comment: It matters whether or not you are using Python 2 or 3 because str() means something completely different in each. You need to edit this question to tell which so people can help you

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this problem that I found is adding `encoding= "utf-8"` in the open function:

```
with open('file.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as file :
   file.write('ñoño')
```

Answer (score 0):

The only error I can spot is,

```
str(texta).encode("utf-8")
```

In it, you are forcing a conversion to str and encoding it. It should be replaced with,

```
texta.encode("utf-8")
```

**EDIT:**

The error stems in the server not giving the correct encoding for the page. So `requests` assumes a `'ISO-8859-1'`. As noted in this [bug](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1604), it is a deliberate decision.

Luckily, `chardet` library correctly detects the `'utf-8'` encoding, so you can do:

```
source.encoding = source.apparent_encoding
chapter = source.text
```

And there won't be any need to manually decode the text in `chapter`, since `requests` uses it to decode the `content` for you.

Comment: It was redundancy, thank you for that but it still doesn't write special characters on my text file :(

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you (wrongly) have utf8 encoded data in a Python3 string. The real cause of that is probably that `requests.content` is already a unicode string, so you should not decode it, but use it directly:

```
    url = 'http://www.wuxiaworld.com/atg-index/atg-chapter-' + str(x) + "/"
    source = requests.get(url)
    chapter = source.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(chapter, 'html.parser')
```

If it is not enough, that means if you still have ’ and – (Unicode `u'\u2019'` and `u'\u2013'`) display as `\xe2\x80\x99` and `\xe2\x80\x93'`, that could be caused by the html page not correctly declaring its encoding. In that case you should first encode to a byte string with latin1 encoding, and then decode it as utf8:

```
chapter = source.content.encode('latin1', 'ignore').decode('utf8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(chapter, 'html.parser')
```

Demonstration:

```
t = u'\xe2\x80\x99 \xe2\x80\x93'
t = t.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

Displays : `u'\u2019 \u2013'`

```
print(t)
```

Displays : `’ –`

Comment: It didn't work saying there is no encode for a bytes content. I looked for some websites on the internet and found that each line of my text document is in Bynary Literal. I will just let my code as is and make a converter from Bynary Literal to String