# Python print french characters to another file

Tags: python, french

Whenever I print a **french** character (for example "é") in **another file** using python, it changes it to a weird character.

`program.py`:

```py
f = open("file.txt", 'w')
print("é, è, ç", file=f)
```

`file.txt`:

```
�, �, �
```

**So please does anyone know how to print out french characters to any other files as they are?**

Comment: Can you try with `f = open("file.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8')`?
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing on text file, accents and special characters not displaying correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761993/writing-on-text-file-accents-and-special-characters-not-displaying-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using UTF-8 encoding:

```
f = open("file.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
print("é, è, ç", file=f)

# é, è, ç
```

> The default encoding is platform dependent, but any encoding supported
> by Python can be passed. See the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module for the list of
> supported encodings.

Answer (score -3):

```
def wordlist(filename):
    f = open(filename, mode='r')
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
    wordlist = [fixCaps(w) for w in re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", text)]
    print(wordlist)
    f.close()
    return wordlist
```

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to the question asked